# Trouble running a giraph job (classnotfoundexception)

Tags: java, hadoop, classnotfoundexception, giraph

I'm attempting to build the SimpleShortestPathsComputation example included with Giraph and run it from within my home directory. Basically, I'm just trying to tweak the SimpleShortestPaths example and run it without any hassle (not quite sure what the best way to go about that would be). My approach was as follows:

SimpleShortestPathsComputaiton.java:

```
import org.apache.giraph.graph.BasicComputation;
......
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.io.IOException;
public class SimpleShortestPathsComputation extends BasicComputation<
    LongWritable, DoubleWritable, FloatWritable, DoubleWritable> { 
......
```

I build it like so:

```
JCC = javac
JFLAGS = "-Xlint"
OUTPUT_CLASS="test"
CLASSPATH = $(HADOOP_HOME)/hadoop-core-0.20.203.0.jar:$(GIRAPH_HOME)/giraph-core/target/giraph-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-0.20.203.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

default: SimpleShortestPathsComputation.class

SimpleShortestPathsComputation.class: SimpleShortestPathsComputation.java
mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_CLASS)
$(JCC) $(JFLAGS) -classpath $(CLASSPATH) -d $(OUTPUT_CLASS)    SimpleShortestPathsComputation.java
jar cvf SimpleShortestPathsComputation.jar -C $(OUTPUT_CLASS)/ .
```

This works fine and I create a jar file named SimpleShortestPathsComputation. I then try running it like so:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-0.20.203.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner /home/hduser/SimpleShortestPathsComputation.jar \
-vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat \
-vip /user/hduser/input/tiny_graph.txt \
-vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat \
-op /user/hduser/output/shortestpaths -w 1 \
/
```

However, this results in the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   /home/hduser/SimpleShortestPathsComputation.jar
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.apache.giraph.utils.ConfigurationUtils.handleComputationClass(ConfigurationUtils.java:470)
at org.apache.giraph.utils.ConfigurationUtils.populateGiraphConfiguration(ConfigurationUtils.java:453)
at org.apache.giraph.utils.ConfigurationUtils.parseArgs(ConfigurationUtils.java:207)
at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction, or link to a resource that explains an easier way of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You know the difference between a class and a jar file?

Comment: Yes... actually I had a typo in the above- I should be trying to run a class and not the jar itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the "[Quick start](https://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html)", actually there are inconsistency with 1.0.0:

(1) argument "-vof" should have been "-of". "-vof" was introduced in 1.1.0 (see [GIRAPH-774](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GIRAPH-774)).

(2) In 1.0.0, there doesn't exist a class called "org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation", change it to "org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsVertex".